# работа с картинкой php

Tags: php, fileupload, photo

Здравствуйте,
Есть база данных строящихся зданий. Ежемесячно надо менять в них фото(одно) на текущее время и данные о расходах для отчета. При изменении цифровых данных (не фото) через форму данные сохраняются, а фото приходится заново загружать. Есть ли какой нибудь способ, если фото не изменилась оставить старое?

Comment: В форму добавьте чекбокс "Не изменять фото" и проверяйте его на сервере перед обработкой фото.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($_FILES['file']['error']!=0)
{
оставляем старое фото
}
else
{
обновляем фото на новое
}
```